# Linq left join into new object

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I haven't done a LEFT JOIN in linq yet, and I am getting very stuck.

At the moment, I have this:

```
var results = (from csr
                               in _context.project_sprint_resource
                           join pr in _context.project_resource
                               on csr.ProjectResourceId equals pr.Id
                            join prpa in _context.project_resource_person_allocation
                                on pr.Id equals prpa.ProjectResourceId
                                where csr.ProjectSprintId == sprintId
                           select new SprintResourceDto
                               {
                                   SprintId = csr.ProjectSprintId,
                                   ProductiveHours = pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                                   ProjectResourceId = pr.Id,
                                   ResourceTypeId = pr.ResourceTypeId,
                                   ResourceType = new ReferenceTypeDto
                                       {
                                           Description = pr.resource_type.Description,
                                           Id = pr.resource_type.Id
                                       },
                                   AssignedHours = pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                                   Person = new PersonDto
                                       {
                                           Id = prpa.Id,
                                           Firstname = prpa.person.Firstname,
                                           Surname = prpa.person.Surname
                                       },
                                       PersonId = prpa.PersonId
                               }).ToList();
            return results.ToList();
```

I need to change it so that the "prpa in _context.project_resource_person_allocation" becomes a LEFT join, as this table might not have a matching row.

It looks like a need an INTO, but the examples I see don't make it clear how.

My other option might be to do it in two queries somehow? But, I'm a SQL person, but yet, finding it hard to grasp how to do a LEFT join in linq.

Edit:
I have progressed a bit, but am having a final issues. I have modified the query, and it seems I am getting the right rows back, BUT... on the cases where there is no right side row (The left join), it crashes, because I can't assign NULL to my Person property (Which is a calss I have created):

```
        var results = (from csr
                           in _context.project_sprint_resource
                       join pr in _context.project_resource
                           on csr.ProjectResourceId equals pr.Id
                       join prpa in _context.project_resource_person_allocation
                           on pr.Id equals prpa.ProjectResourceId into sub
                       from subq in sub.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where csr.ProjectSprintId == sprintId
                       select new SprintResourceDto
                           {
                               SprintId = csr.ProjectSprintId,
                               ProductiveHours = pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                               ProjectResourceId = pr.Id,
                               AssignedHours = pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                               ResourceTypeId = pr.ResourceTypeId,
                               PersonId = subq != null ? subq.PersonId : (int?)null,
                               ResourceStartDate = pr.StartDate,
                               ResourceEndDate = pr.EndDate,
                               Deleted = csr.Deleted.HasValue,
                               ResourceType = new ReferenceTypeDto
                                   {
                                       Description = pr.resource_type.Description,
                                       Id = pr.resource_type.Id
                                   },
                               Person = null
                                //= subq != null ? new PersonDto
                                //   {
                                //       Id = subq != null ? subq.Id : 0,
                                //       Firstname = subq != null ? subq.person.Firstname : "",
                                //       Surname = subq != null ? subq.person.Surname : ""
                                //   } : null,
                           });
        return results.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var ne = e;
        return null;
    }
```

The error happens when I attempt to assign NULL to Person. I get an error saying that:

> Unable to create a null constant value of type
>   'SharedObjects.EntityObjects.PersonDto'. Only entity types,
>   enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.

The PersonDto object is defined like this:

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public decimal GrossSalary { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", Firstname, Surname); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `default(Person)` instead of `null`

Comment: Using that, i get: {"Unable to create a null constant value of type 'SharedObjects.EntityObjects.PersonDto'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context."}

Comment: What is the PersonDto class? can you post a bit of it?

Comment: I've added the class definition for the PersonDto now.

Comment: What type is `SprintResourceDto.Person`?

Comment: Hi Daniel - I've now added the class definition for the Person (Which is a PersonDto) to the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.
Checking for NULL was the problem. It seems the sub query is never NULL.
Rather, checking for subq.Count() > 0

It seems it creates the 'List' of items, but because of the 'left join' I'm trying, it just does add any items to the sub.

Adding the .Count check has resolved it, and I get perfect results.

Comment: Ahhh, now I see... So simple in the end!

Comment: Yeah, 3 days of going crazy. Would be nice if the people who designed linq ... could make a left join more simple. I now dred my next one! :) But yeah, the logic, I guess, makes sense. Thanks for the efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Hey can you try this please an let me know what you get?

```
var results = (from csr in _context.project_sprint_resource
               join pr in _context.project_resource
                   on csr.ProjectResourceId equals pr.Id
               join prpa in _context.project_resource_person_allocation
                   on pr.Id equals prpa.ProjectResourceId into sub
               from subq in sub.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where csr.ProjectSprintId == sprintId
               select new { csr = csr, pr = pr, subq = subq}).AsEnumerable(x => 
                   select new SprintResourceDto
                       {
                           SprintId = x.csr.ProjectSprintId,
                           ProductiveHours = x.pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                           ProjectResourceId = x.pr.Id,
                           AssignedHours = x.pr.ExpectedProductiveHours,
                           ResourceTypeId = x.pr.ResourceTypeId,
                           PersonId = x.subq != null ? x.subq.PersonId : (int?)null,
                           ResourceStartDate = pr.StartDate,
                           ResourceEndDate = x.pr.EndDate,
                           Deleted = x.csr.Deleted.HasValue,
                           ResourceType = new ReferenceTypeDto
                               {
                                   Description = x.pr.resource_type.Description,
                                   Id = x.pr.resource_type.Id
                               },
                           Person = x.subq != null ? new PersonDto
                               {
                                   Id = x.subq.Id,
                                   Firstname x.subq.person.Firstname
                                   Surname = subq.person.Surname
                               } : null
                       });
    return results.ToList();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    var ne = e; // What on earth is this by the way?
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Haha. Dave, I was just having an exception not being shown. This was a temp fix. Ok. Trying your code now. Will report back.

Comment: Dave, this didn't work, however, it moved me towards the right answer. The problem was, subq is never NULL. But subq.Count() = 0. That check solved it.